# Write list of addresses to smart contract in one transaction - String Array to contract

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity

I want to send several addresses to my smart contract and the contract should save them in a map (e.g.) - My aim is to give theses addresses a special access control role.

How can I iterate about the array, which was given to the function?

Or how can I give my contract/function this list/array of addresses?

```
mapping(address => address) winnerAddresses;
// set the addresses in store
function setStore(address[] _winnerAddresses) public {
  winnerAddresses[_winnerAddresses] = _winnerAddresses;
}
```

After we have save the addresses to the contract, I would call the addUserToRole function for each given address.

Would be happy if you could help me!
Thanks a lot
mh

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you can store the values as an `array` instead of a `mapping`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    address[] winnerAddresses; // store as an array

    function setStore(address[] memory _winnerAddresses) public {
        winnerAddresses = _winnerAddresses;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer to store them in a `mapping`, you need to iterate through the input `array` and store each item separately.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    // default value is `false`, so by default there's no winner
    // when you set the `winnerAddress[<some_address>]` to `true`, it means that this address is a winner
    mapping(address => bool) winnerAddresses;

    function setStore(address[] memory _winnerAddresses) public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < _winnerAddresses.length; i++) {
            winnerAddresses[_winnerAddresses[i]] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It's currently (Solidity 0.8) not possible to pass a `mapping` as a function argument.

Comment: Thanks, but it thought it is not possible to have an "open" array which have no defined length?

Comment: @LOM There are two types of arrays in Solidity. Fixed size, and dynamic size (this is what you probably mean by the "open"). You can find the docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html#arrays)... There are some limitations working with arrays in memory - such as you can't resize them (in memory). But here, you're working with the storage array, so you can safely resize it (from the default 0, to the length of the input parameter).